# Python Shell expected an indented block

Tags: python

I tried this code at the interpreter prompt:

```
>>> x = 7
>>> if x > 5:
... print("five")
```

I got this error message:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    print("five") 
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Why?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 9):

In the shell you should do this:

```
>>> if x > 5:
...    print("five")
```

That is, add an indent block after the ":"

Comment: No problem @ManeHambardzumyan

Comment: I have added an indentation block but it doesn't end when I press enter again

Comment: @ikamen you must be missing some parenthesis or something like that. If your parentheses are ok it should execute the command. If that is not the case, perhaps you are missing another enter. Usually it's two enters: one for the next line and another to tell python "hey I'm done, please execute"

Answer (score 4):

Indentation is important in Python. You need to indent your `print` statement with a few spaces or a tab otherwise the interpreter will think your `if` is empty.

```
>>> if x > 5:
...    print("five")
```